# When two open covers refine each other are they already the same?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, manifolds

If two covers $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ and $(V_j)_{j\in J}$ of a topological space (assume both to be non redundant, i.e. $U_i\subset U_j\Rightarrow i=j$) are refinements of each other. Does this already imply that these covers are the same up to permutation of I and J.

Comment: The answer here really just uses the definition of refinement and nonredundtant.

Comment: What have you tried? State the definition of refinement, for example.

Comment: A refinement $D = U_{\beta} (\beta \in B)$ of a cover $C = V_{\alpha} (\alpha \in A)$ if for all $\beta \in B$ there is some $\alpha \in A$ such that $U_{\beta} \subseteq V_{\alpha}$ Now does this imply any bijections?